# multiple featured image wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

I want to make a business page that has a logo and a photo of the business itself.
I use a custom post-type for this. However i can not make the second featured image to work.
I want to make it work without a plugin.
this is my code:

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 
        'Bedrijven', array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Bedrijven' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'bedrijf' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'comments',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'MultiPostThumbnails',
            'page-attributes',)

        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );


if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
  new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
     'label' => 'Thumbnail Image',
     'id' => 'thumbnail-image',
     'post_type' => 'bedrijven'
   ) );
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it simply by this plugin:
[dynamic featured image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/)

and you can get these multiple image on front end by this way:

```
 if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {
    global $dynamic_featured_image;

    $featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images( );
    //print_r($featured_images);

    //You can now loop through the image to display them as required
    foreach($featured_images as $featured_image) {
        echo "<img src='".$featured_image['full']."'></a>";
    }

 }
```

Comment: You sir are a legend!

Answer (score 2):

Well,

Some plugins are available for multiple featured image i.e. [Dynamic Featured Image](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/), [Multiple   Featured Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-featured-images/).
You can easily manage them through these plugins.

Comment: I want to use as little plugins as possible. But if i can't get it to work i will use one of those plugins. Thanks